# Do I need a schema with Meteor?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, meteor-collection2

I'm following a React and Meteor tutorial on Lynda.com and everything is going fine until I'm asked to edit the packages file  inside of the meteor directory. I"m asked to replace

**static-html** with **aldeed:collection2**

When I do this, it returns this error in the console

```
modules.js?hash=bb4e7ba9d25b4bdb1fcceae6a393ccb3e1eaf34b:4370 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Here is my dependencies below, do I need a schema to set up a 
Meteor database?

```
{
  "name": "somename",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.3.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.3",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: no, you don't need a schema. And that request is odd. I don't see how aldeed:collection2 would be a replacement for static-html.

Comment: I agree, collection2 is not a replacement for static-html - the error message is clearly misleading. If you want to add schema support, it's quite easy, and I would recommend simpl-schema